# Ionic Side Menu

Tags: angularjs, ionic-framework

so I am currently doing a side menu for my Single Page Application, I got the side menu working, but I cannot display the main content. I am not sure what went wrong. I cannot display the word hello world in my page. Any one has an idea?

Here is my code

```
  <ion-tab title="Draft" ng-controller="textController">
            <ion-side-menus>
                <ion-side-menu-content>
                    <ion-header-bar class="bar-positive">
                        <button class="button button-icon" ng-click="toggleLeft()" menu-toggle="left">
                            <i class="icon ion-navicon"></i>
                        </button>

                        <h1 class="title"> Details</h1>
                    </ion-header-bar>
                </ion-side-menu-content>


                <ion-side-menu side="left">
                    <header class="bar bar-header bar-assertive">
                        <h1 class="title">Menu</h1>
                    </header>

                    <ion-list>
                        <ion-item>
                            Home
                        </ion-item>
                        <ion-item>
                            About
                        </ion-item>
                        <ion-item>
                            Setting
                        </ion-item>
                        <ion-item>
                            Log out
                        </ion-item>
                    </ion-list>
                </ion-side-menu>
            </ion-side-menus>

            <ion-content>

              Hello World

            </ion-content>
        </ion-tab>
```

Here is my controller:

```
angular.module('app')

.controller('textController', function ($scope, $ionicSideMenuDelegate) {
    $scope.toggleLeft = function () {
        $ionicSideMenuDelegate.toggleLeft();
    }
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Following the official Ionic documentation (http://ionicframework.com/docs/guide/starting.html) it seems that your "Hello World" content should be inside a `<ion-side-menu-content>` tag, not a simple `<ion-content>`. Please try that and let me know if that solves your problem.

Comment: Hi rssedoardo, thank you for your help. I have tried your suggestion, and it actually help!! :) However, I am not really sure why you can't put stuff in <ion-content> instead you have to use <ion-side-menu-content> when you are using the side menu.

Comment: The `<ion-side-menu-content>` is used to identify the "center content" of your application; inside those tags you might have multiple tags (see the link that I inserted in my answer, you can see how they use multiple tags inside that `<ion-side-menu-content>`). Remember that you might want to attach different controllers to different tags. I am glad I was able to help!

Comment: Hi rssedoardo, just going to let you know that, you actually still need to include the <ion-content> tag inside the <ion-side-menu-content> like this

<ion-side menu-content>
        <ion-content>
                   stuff and things go here
        </ion-content
</ion-side-menu-content>

Otherwise, you will get this error:  Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'freeze' of null